How to Add New Analyzers to Existing Fields in Azure AI Search Without Creating a New Index?
I've been working with Azure AI Search and encountered an issue while trying to change the structure of an existing index. Initially, I thought it was not possible to update an index until I tried adding to the JSON file and received this error:
"An index with the name 'myindex' in service 'myservice' could not be updated. Index update not allowed because it would cause downtime. In order to add new analyzers, normalizers, tokenizers, token filters, or character filters to an existing index, or modify its similarity settings, set the 'allowIndexDowntime' query parameter to 'true' in the index update request. Note that this operation will put your index offline for at least a few seconds, causing your indexing and query requests to fail. Performance and write availability of the index can be impaired for several minutes after the index is updated, or longer for very large indexes"
Following the guidance, I updated the index using the allowIndexDowntime=true parameter in my PUT request, which should allow changes with some temporary downtime.
However, when I attempt to add a new analyzer to one of my fields, I receive a 400 response with this error message:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "OperationNotAllowed",
        "message": "Existing field 'myFieldName' cannot be changed.",
        "details": [
            {
                "code": "CannotChangeExistingField",
                "message": "Existing field 'myFieldName' cannot be changed."
            }
        ]
    }
}

Is there a way to add new analyzers to existing fields without having to recreate the entire index each time? If anyone has experience with this or knows a workaround, your advice would be greatly appreciated!

Add a new field like myNewField with the desired analyzer. Populate this new field with the same data you had in myFieldName.

If adding a new field won’t cut it (maybe you’re super attached to the old field), then you’ll have to go the full route of recreating the index.


How to Add New Analyzers to Existing Fields in Azure AI Search Without Creating a New Index?

We cannot directly add new analyzers to existing fields in Azure Cognitive Search without recreating the index. Azure Cognitive Search imposes strict limitations on modifying existing fields after an index is created.

The only way to change field definitions is by recreating the index.

Exporting the current index schema. modify the schema JSON file to include the new analyzer and apply it to the field that requires it.
current index schema:
{
  "name": "myindex",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "myFieldName",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": false,
      "analyzer": "standard"
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
}

Now, add the new analyzer configuration you need for that you need to define the new analyzer in the "analyzers" section.
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "myFieldName_analyzed",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": false,
      "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
    }
  ],
  "analyzers": [
    {
      "name": "custom_analyzer",
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "standard",
      "tokenFilters": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
    }
  ]
}

POST Request to Reindex Data for the New Field here is the response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "message": "Documents successfully reindexed for new field '***********'."
}


Updated:
Index API:
POST https://<search-service-name>.search.windows.net/indexes/<index-name>/docs/index?api-version=2021-04-30-Preview
Content-Type: application/json
api-key: <api-key>

{
  "value": [
    {
      "@search.action": "upload",
      "id": "123",
      "field1": "data",
      "field2": "data"
    }
  ]
}

To list and filter blobs by the Last-Modified date using py SDK:
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from datetime import datetime

# Initialize BlobServiceClient
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("<your_connection_string>")
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("<container_name>")

# Retrieve the last synced timestamp (from your storage or database)
last_synced = datetime.strptime("2023-10-21T12:00:00Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

# List blobs in the container
blobs_list = container_client.list_blobs()

# Process blobs modified after the last sync
for blob in blobs_list:
    last_modified = blob['properties']['last_modified']
    if last_modified > last_synced:
        # Process the blob (e.g., push to Azure AI Search)
        print(f"Processing {blob['name']}")

# After processing, update the last synced timestamp
new_last_synced = datetime.utcnow()


Thanks for your answer. My main concern is reindexing my data. In my original instance, I have hundreds of GBs of data. When I create a new index, should I manually push all the data from my database to Azure AI Search? Is there a way to directly pull from my old index to the new index?

If the data source is compatible (e.g., Azure SQL Database, Azure Blob Storage), configure an indexer that points to the data source. update the index schema create the new index. run it, and it will pull data.

Thanks for the information. I store my data in an Azure SQL Database, but I'm not sure if my setup is fully compatible. I have been pushing my data manually in short intervals, but since indexers sync only every 5 minutes, that's not frequent enough for my needs. Additionally, my data is stored in a relational database, and I perform a lot of computations to flatten the data before it's ready for indexing. Given this, I'm uncertain if indexers can effectively pull my data. Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Once you have the data extracted, you can reindex it into the new index. You can use the Index API or SDK to push data to the new index.

Azure Functions can serve as a custom ETL pipeline it triggers automatically whenever data changes in the Azure SQL Database. try this approach it gives you full control over the transformation and indexing frequency.

I'm planning to create Azure Blob Storage to manage data syncing for my Azure AI Search setup. My aim is to utilize the 'last modified' date and store a 'last synced' timestamp so I can sync only the changes since the last sync point. This would function like an indexer but be manually managed.
However, since Azure Blob Storage lacks querying functionality, how can I efficiently retrieve the top 1000 changes after the last sync point?
Does anyone have experience with this approach? Any insights on feasibility, best practices, or potential challenges would be greatly appreciated.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
